# Alter MySQL Trigger within Transaction

Tags: mysql, triggers, transactions

After an `ALTER TABLE` command, it is common to need a update a trigger that is firing based upon data being inserted, updated, or deleted on the altered table. Unfortunately, `DROP TRIGGER` and `CREATE TRIGGER` cause [implicit commits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html), so one cannot simply place these two commands in a single transaction followed by a commit.

**Is there a way to update a MySQL Trigger so that either the old or new variant of the trigger is active whenever data within the table with the trigger is manipulated?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify trigger atomically using table locking:

```
LOCK TABLES `mytable` WRITE;  

 DELIMITER $$    
   DROP TRIGGER `mytable_tri` $$  
   CREATE TRIGGER `mytable_tri` AFTER INSERT ON `mytable`  
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
      /* ...... trigger code ......... */  
   END;  
   $$  
 DELIMITER ;  

 UNLOCK TABLES;
```

It works in MySQL 5.6 and newer.

I have written a blogpost about that some time ago: [http://vkwww.blogspot.com/2014/07/alter-trigger-in-mysql.html](http://vkwww.blogspot.cz/2014/07/alter-trigger-in-mysql.html)